# Pass parameter to Javascript from HTML and Flask for onload and click

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, flask

I am trying to generate a custom file name when downloading the file through onload functionaly. Below is my html code followed by javascript code.

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-right mb-3">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="download"> download pdf</button>
</div>
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("download")
            .addEventListener("click", () => {
                const invoice = this.document.getElementById("invoice");
                console.log(invoice);
                console.log(window);
                var opt = {
                    margin: 1,
                    filename: 'myfile.pdf',
                    image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
                    html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
                    jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' }
                };
                html2pdf().from(invoice).set(opt).save();
            })
    }
</script>
```

from the above code I would like to send a dynamic name to the filename instead of myfile.pdf.
I am using flask as the frame work and sqlite3 as db.
I would like to have output as singala_invoice.pdf whereas singala would be coming from flask like {{ invoice_details['user_name'] }}.
I would be great if someone can help with the query.

Comment: Providing server-side code (Flask) will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the Jinja variable at any place you want in the template so long as you have passed the variables `invoice_details` and `user_name` when calling `render_template`:

```
filename: '{{ invoice_details[user_name] }}_invoce.pdf',
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the response. I found a way to make it work. I have modified the code as below.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        myFunction("{{ invoice_details[4] }}");
    };
    function myFunction(name2){
    document.getElementById("download")
        .addEventListener("click", () => {
            const invoice = this.document.getElementById("invoice");
            console.log(invoice);
            console.log(window);
    
            var opt = {
                margin: 1,
                filename: name2+'invoice.pdf',
                image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
                html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
                jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' }
            };
            html2pdf().from(invoice).set(opt).save();
        })
        }
</script>
```